# Center of Applications from X to a group G

Tags: group-theory

I have to demonstrate: Let B a group and X a nonempty set. So, $$Z[Aplc(X,G)]=Aplc[X,Z(G)]$$ 
where $Z$ is the center of the group. And $Aplc(X,G)$ is the set of all the applications from X to G. ($Aplc[X,G]$ is a group with $\circ$)

**My little work.**
Im so lost in this, but I try make a double implication. From an element of $Z[Aplc(X,G)]$ reach an element of $Aplc[X,Z(G)]$.

$\Rightarrow)$ Let $g\in Z[Aplc(X,G)]$, so $g\in Aplc(X,G)$ and $ag=ga$ $\forall a\in Aplc(X,G)$. But I see a problem and this occurs when I try to define the characteristic of $g$ in the center. Well, ik that $g\circ a=a\circ g$ so I get $g(a(x))=a(g(x))$ and then I don't know what to make. What should I do for demonstrate that $g\in Aplc[X,Z(G)]$ :(

$\Leftarrow)$ Well, I start with Let $n\in Aplc[X,Z(G)]$ so, $n:X\to Z(G)$. And I have to show that $n\in Z[Aplc(X,G)]$. For that, I need to see that $an=na$ $\forall a\in Aplc(X,G)]$. Well, i try that with $$an(x)=(a\circ n)(x)=a(n(x))$$
And I don't know how to proceed. What should I do. :'(

Any help would be awesome. I've tried this all this days and nothing works.

PDT: I think I can make this finding an isomorphism between the two sets. Buuut, 
I could not find it and I discard that idea.

Thanks to all!

Comment: Should the mention in opening of "a group $B$" actually be a reference to a group $G$?  ($B$ does not appear subsequently in the body of the Question.)

Comment: Yes. Sorry, the group mentioned is $G$ and not $B$.

Comment: Can you provide some source, or define an 'application'? As you might imagine, it is *impossible* to get meaningful results from a search engine when the words you have to work with are 'application' 'center' 'group' 'set' etc.

Comment: Application is a function. Center, well, is the center of a gruop. $Z(G)={b\in G | ab=ba \forall a\in G}$. And a group and a set I dont know what should define. :)

Comment: So an application is just an arbitrary function $X\to G$ where $X$ is just a set? Then for $g, a \in Aplc(X, G)$, $g\circ a$ doesn't make sense (unless $X=G$). I think you mean $(ga)(x) = g(x)a(x)$, multiplication taken in $G$, for all $x \in X$

Comment: That's a great point. I got the same error but I think that was my fault because probably we should use the normality hypothesis and you're done. 
I'll try.